# List<t> Serialization performance issue

Tags: c#, serialization

suppose we have list of 1000 string or object, serialize it in file and next time want to update one of them and serialize it again.

current scenario : serialize 1000 item. deserialize all of them update one of the element and then serialize all 1000 elements again. 
is it a better way to do this that we don't need to save\load all of items to update just one element?

**UPDATE**

all of my data is in the instance of list, itemTosave. below class serialize the itemTosave.

```
[System.Serializable]
internal sealed class SaveAndLoadContainer : ISerializable {

private  List<SaveAndLoadItem> loadedItems;
public  static SaveAndLoadContainer  Instance_Save;
public  static SaveAndLoadContainer  Instance_Load;
private  List<SaveAndLoadItem> loadedItems;
public List<SaveAndLoadItem> LoadedItems {
    get {
        return this.loadedItems;
    }
}   

public  SaveAndLoadContainer(){
    Instance_Save = this;
}
private SaveAndLoadContainer(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext contex){
    loadedItems = (List<SaveAndLoadItem>)info.GetValue("UnsavedItems", typeof(List<SaveAndLoadItem>));
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.Clear(); 
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.TrimExcess();)
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.AddRange(loadedItems);
}

public void GetObjectData (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context){
    List<SaveAndLoadItem> unsavedItems = SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave;
    info.AddValue("UnsavedItems", unsavedItems, typeof(List<SaveAndLoadItem>));
}

}
```

SaveAndLoadItem class is :

```
[System.Serializable]
internal sealed class SaveAndLoadItem {
public SaveAndLoadItem(){
    UniqueName = "--Nothing--";
    Value = null;
    ValueType = null;   
    IsClient = false;
}
public SaveAndLoadItem(string uniqueName, object value,Type typeOfValue,bool isClient){
    UniqueName = uniqueName;
    Value = value;
    ValueType = typeOfValue;
    IsClient = isClient;
}

public string UniqueName;
public System.Object Value;
public Type   ValueType;
public bool   IsClient;

}
```

Comment: Instead of adding an answer to add more information, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a list of strings, you should just work with a text file.

In case of objects, if updating a single object is significantly common compared to bulk read/writes, then you should either serialize each object individually or batch them using a partitioning scheme. The optimum partitioning scheme would depend on your use case. For example, if it's a list of Contacts, you could partition by the first letter of their lastname.

Another option is to serialize individual objects and record each object in a relational database, e.g. Sql Server. You can have a table like the following to record your serialized objects in a binary column:

```
CREATE TABLE Objects
(
    Id varchar(255),
    Bytes varbinary
)
```

When the size of byte blobs are very small (e.g. >4KB), a relational database will perform better than the file system.

Comment: i can't use database and objects in list doesn't have any relation to each other but i can serialize each item in the list separately and give them a unique name but how can i retrieve them and put them in list again. i don't know each object's unique name when deserializing. is there any way to deserialize objects with its type.cause all objects in the list are same type.

Comment: it's a bit hard to give you a good answer when not knowing the details. can you include some code in the question, showing the list and the type of objects inside that list?

Answer (score 0):

all of my data is in the instance of list, itemTosave.
below class serialize the  itemTosave.

```
[System.Serializable]
internal sealed class SaveAndLoadContainer : ISerializable {

private  List<SaveAndLoadItem> loadedItems;
public  static SaveAndLoadContainer  Instance_Save;
public  static SaveAndLoadContainer  Instance_Load;
private  List<SaveAndLoadItem> loadedItems;
public List<SaveAndLoadItem> LoadedItems {
    get {
        return this.loadedItems;
    }
}   

public  SaveAndLoadContainer(){
    Instance_Save = this;
}
private SaveAndLoadContainer(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext contex){
    loadedItems = (List<SaveAndLoadItem>)info.GetValue("UnsavedItems", typeof(List<SaveAndLoadItem>));
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.Clear(); 
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.TrimExcess();)
    SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave.AddRange(loadedItems);
}

public void GetObjectData (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context){
    List<SaveAndLoadItem> unsavedItems = SaveAndLoadManager.ItemsToSave;
    info.AddValue("UnsavedItems", unsavedItems, typeof(List<SaveAndLoadItem>));
}
```

}

SaveAndLoadItem class is :

```
[System.Serializable]
internal sealed class SaveAndLoadItem {
public SaveAndLoadItem(){
    UniqueName = "--Nothing--";
    Value = null;
    ValueType = null;   
    IsClient = false;
}
public SaveAndLoadItem(string uniqueName, object value,Type typeOfValue,bool isClient){
    UniqueName = uniqueName;
    Value = value;
    ValueType = typeOfValue;
    IsClient = isClient;
}

public string UniqueName;
public System.Object Value;
public Type   ValueType;
public bool   IsClient;
```

}